# Extract particular line from CLOB - ORACLE

Tags: oracle

I have field in a Oracle database of type CLOB. I extract the first line alone from this CLOB filed. Here's an example of the content:

```
"<div class="pi-tier3"><div class="pi-pdpmainbody"><p><b>FIT</b></p><p>Core Indy - Compression </p>
<p><b>PRO</b></p><ul>
<li>ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0</li>
<li>ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0</li>
<li>ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0</li>
<li></li>
<li>ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0</li>
</ul>
<p><b>PRP</b></p><ul>
<li>100%</li>
<li>DRY</li>
</ul>
<p>ABCDEF:PmId12345RmLn1VlId0</p>
</div></div>"
```

The result should look like this:

```
"<div class="pi-tier3"><div class="pi-pdpmainbody"><p><b>FIT</b></p><p>Core Indy - Compression </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you truly want to return the characters from the beginning of the clob value to the characters before the first newline (chr 10), then here is an example:

```
create table tab1 (c1 clob);
insert into tab1 values ('line 1' || chr(10) || 'line 2');
select dbms_lob.substr(c1, dbms_lob.instr(c1, chr(10))-1, 1) from tab1;

DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(C1,DBMS_LOB.INSTR(C1,CHR(10))-1,1)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
line 1
```

Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_lob.htm#ARPLS600) out for more information.

EDIT 04-MAY-2023

If a CLOB has only one line and that line is allowed to not have a trailing newline, then you have to write code that would scan the entire CLOB for a newline so that you return the entire CLOB's characters.

You can do that irrespective of performance problems if you treat the substr's 2nd parameter as a more complex expression. If you make it a decode or a case statement then you can make the expression return either what it is now or the size of the clob if the instr function doesn't find a newline.

Comment: Thanks @jeff6times7 but this query is failing when the CLOB has only one row.

Comment: @GanzRicanz When you say "has only one row" do you mean "only one line" or do you mean when the query returns multiple rows?

Comment: Sorry, it's failing when the CLOB filed contains only one line.

Comment: If you mean the CLOB contains no newline character when you say "only one line", then you introduced a new definition for the word "line". It's reasonable to assume that every set of characters that represents a line will always be followed by a newline character.

Answer (score 0):

I would do that using `REGEXP_SUBSTR`, like so:

```
select
REGEXP_SUBSTR(
 '<div class="pi-tier3"><div class="pi-pdpmainbody"><p><b>FIT</b></p><p>Core Indy - Compression </p>
<p><b>PRO</b></p><ul>'
, '^.*$', 1, 1, 'm')
from dual;
```

Cheers

Comment: I can get your expression to work if I use 'm' instead of 'nm' as your answer uses. The 'n' allows dot to match the newline character which causes the expression to match the whole input.

Comment: Edited the response and removed the 'n' frm the 'nm', I left it over from another case.. try it like so